# React.js : net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: reactjs

I receive this error in any project I've worked,I don't understand what happened, all of the code is correct but it still displays this error, please help me

> about:client:1 GET
> chrome-extension://adlpodnneegcnbophopdmhedicjbcgco/content/styles.css
> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Échec du chargement de la carte source par les
> Outils de développement : Impossible de charger le contenu de
> chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/js/intercom-link-expand-loader.js.map :
> Erreur HTTP : code d'état 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Échec du
> chargement de la carte source par les Outils de développement :
> Impossible de charger le contenu de
> chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/js/content.js.map :
> Erreur HTTP : code d'état 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Échec du
> chargement de la carte source par les Outils de développement :
> Impossible de charger le contenu de
> chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/js/companion-bubble.js.map :
> Erreur HTTP : code d'état 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Échec du
> chargement de la carte source par les Outils de développement :
> Impossible de charger le contenu de
> chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/js/intercom-link-expand-loader.js.map :
> Erreur HTTP : code d'état 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: thanks I will try

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be to do with a Chrome extension, rather than a react issue.
I just had the same issue and turning off the "Loom – Free Screen and Cam Recorder" chrome extension fixed it for me - no more errors!

Answer (score 0):

precede the static files with **process.env.PUBLIC_URL** if you are looking for them in the **PUBLIC folder**
for example

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href='/assets/css/style.css'/>
```

in

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+ '/assets/css/style.css'} />
```